# select records where words from a table appear in a field on a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables: 1 with a list of messages in a field and another table with 1 column with a list of keywords. I need to select all records where one or more of the keywords appear in the `MessageText` field.

This is what I have so far but doesn't work:

```
SELECT MessageID, MessageText
FROM Messages
WHERE MessageText LIKE (
     SELECT  '%'+Keyword+'%' 
     FROM keywords_table)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `EXISTS()`

```
select MessageID, MessageText
from   Messages m
where  exists
       (
            select *
            from   keywords_table k
            where  m.MessageText like '%' + k.Keyword + '%' 
       )
```